# Sorting prior to specific field if not set then use the other

Tags: xslt, sorting, xslt-1.0

iam trying to sort my results prior to PublishingStartDate and if this date is not set then by Modified.

what i wrote so far is this

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Rows">
    <xsl:sort order="descending" select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string((@Modified|@PublishingStartDate[normalize-space() != ''])[last()]) ,1043 ,'yyyyMM')"/>
```

but what it is doing is that it always sorts by Modified attribute.
Can you please advice me what am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT1: Input XML, desired is to have it sorted by PublishingStartDate descending

```
<dsQueryResponse>
<Rows>
    <Row PublishingStartDate="13-1-2013 0:00:00" Modified="2012-12-07 09:35:16">
</Rows>
```

Comment: We can't help unless we see your input XML and your expected output XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select expression will match whichever of the two attributes comes last in the source, not whichever comes last in that expression.

Try replacing :

```
(@Modified|@PublishingStartDate[normalize-space() != ''])[last()])
```

with

```
(@Modified[not(../@PublishingStartDate[normalize-space() != ''])]|@PublishingStartDate[normalize-space() != ''])
```

Comment: hi, probably you have a typo in your code, it doesnt work for me,thanks for helping

Comment: Oops, yeah, sorry. I copied & pasted from one character further than I should have. Corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

with Flynn1179 I was able to run it, corrected xslt is here

```
<xsl:sort order="descending" select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string((@Modified[not(../@PublishingStartDate[normalize-space() != ''])]|@PublishingStartDate[normalize-space() != ''])) ,1043 ,'yyyyMM')"/>
```